# DNS error with MySQL integration with kubernetes cluster

Tags: kubernetes, minikube, coredns

**What happened:**

I am trying to create a service endpoint using the `externalName` spec to allow my microservices running inside the pods to access a local MySQL server on my local host.

This is the relevant section for the yaml file:

```
apiVersion: v1 
kind: Service 
metadata: 
  name: mysql 
  namespace: default 
spec: 
  type: ExternalName 
  externalName: host.minikube.internal
```

**What you expected to happen:**
I expect to be able to connect but my SpringBoot containers are showing that the mysql connection is not working. I have tested the microservices and it is working in Docker with the same MySQL database.

**How to reproduce it (as minimally and precisely as possible):**

Normal installation of minikube and kubernetes, running the `dnsutils` image from https://k8s.io/examples/admin/dns/dnsutils.yaml with the mysql service given above.

**Anything else we need to know?:**

I have tested out the troubleshooting detailed here (https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/dns-debugging-resolution/) but it did not resolve the problem. When running:

```
kubectl exec -i -t dnsutils -- nslookup mysql.default
```

I get the following message:

```
Server: 10.96.0.10
Address: 10.96.0.10#53

mysql.default.svc.cluster.local canonical name = host.minikube.internal.
** server can't find host.minikube.internal: SERVFAIL

command terminated with exit code 1
```

I have verified that `CoreDNS` is installed and running:

```
NAME READY STATUS RESTARTS AGE
coredns-f9fd979d6-z58cr 1/1 Running 0 31m
```

Endpoints are exposed:

```
NAME ENDPOINTS AGE
kube-dns 172.17.0.2:53,172.17.0.2:53,172.17.0.2:9153 32m
```

My `/etc/resolv.conf` only has one entry:

```
nameserver 192.168.53.145
```

**Environment:**

Kubernetes version (use kubectl version):

```
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"20", GitVersion:"v1.20.0", GitCommit:"af46c47ce925f4c4ad5cc8d1fca46c7b77d13b38", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2020-12-08T17:59:43Z", GoVersion:"go1.15.5", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"windows/amd64"}

Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"19", GitVersion:"v1.19.4", GitCommit:"d360454c9bcd1634cf4cc52d1867af5491dc9c5f", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2020-11-11T13:09:17Z", GoVersion:"go1.15.2", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
```

Cloud provider or hardware configuration:
Local Windows 10 Pro x64 running Kubernetes with Minikube
OS (e.g: cat /etc/os-release):
`NAME=Buildroot VERSION=2020.02.7 ID=buildroot VERSION_ID=2020.02.7 PRETTY_NAME="Buildroot 2020.02.7`"

Kernel (e.g. uname -a): Linux minikube `4.19.150 #1 SMP Fri Nov 6 15:58:07 PST 2020 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

Install tools: Installed using the relevant kubectl and minikube .exe files
Network plugin and version (if this is a network-related bug):

Others:

Comment: There is a known issue described on [github](https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/issues/8439). I will explain further in a minute.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This problem seems to be close related to `Minikube` [issue](https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/issues/8439) described on github.

You can see, that in your `Pod` in the `/etc/hosts` file - there isn't any `host.minikube.internal` entry:

```
$ kubectl exec -it dnsutils -- cat /etc/hosts | grep "host.minikube.internal"
$
```

On the `Minikube` host you are able to reach `host.minikube.internal` because `Minikube` (version **v1.10+**) adds this `hostname` entry to `/etc/hosts` file. You can find more information in [Host access | minikube](https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/handbook/host-access/).

This is example from my `Minikube` (I'm using docker driver):

```
user@minikube:~$ kubectl exec -it dnsutils -- cat /etc/hosts | grep "host.minikube.internal"
user@minikube:~$
user@minikube:~$ minikube ssh
docker@minikube:~$ cat /etc/hosts | grep host.minikube.internal 
192.168.49.1    host.minikube.internal
docker@minikube:~$ ping host.minikube.internal
PING host.minikube.internal (192.168.49.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from host.minikube.internal (192.168.49.1): icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.075 ms
64 bytes from host.minikube.internal (192.168.49.1): icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.067 ms
```

`host.minikube.internal` is only the entry in the `/etc/hosts` file, therefore `nslookup` can't correctly resolve it (`nslookup` queries name servers **ONLY**.).

```
docker@minikube:~$ nslookup host.minikube.internal
Server:         192.168.49.1
Address:        192.168.49.1#53

** server can't find host.minikube.internal: NXDOMAIN
```

The only workaround I think may help in some cases is adding `hostAliases` to `Deployment`/`Pod` manifest files:

```
...
spec:
  hostAliases:
  - ip: "192.168.49.1" # minikube IP
    hostnames:
    - "host.minikube.internal" # one or more hostnames that should resolve to the above address
  containers:
  - name: dnsutils
    image: gcr.io/kubernetes-e2e-test-images/dnsutils:1.3
...
```

Comment: @WytrzymałyWiktor I tried using HostAlias but it has failed to resolve as well. I read online that some people have had success with it while some people haven’t. Suspect this might be a bug, have added on to the GitHub thread as well! But for now HostAlias might be the best best for a temporary fix for those whom it works for.

Comment: Accepting this answer as this is the best viable solution for now. Otherwise, the other option is to run a MySQL pod and add a service definition to connect to it. To access it from your local env, you can expose it with a load balancer endpoint and use MYSQL workbench to connect to it directly while running minikube tunnel.